# Powershell cmdlet listing services manufacturer

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to list the services' manufacturer in powershell ?

[image]

Comment: Powershell is used primarily for tool making.....I don't see how this is irrelevant.

Comment: Computer management thru Powershell blurs the line between general computing and programming. Admins, now, are often required to program for general computing. There are hardly any programmers on Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hiding in the versioninfo property of the file pointed to by the pathname property.  Also, the pathname property seems to have quotes in the value.

This worked to get the first one.  Probably won't work for all of them:

```
get-childitem -path ((get-wmiobject win32_service | select-object -first 1 -expand pathname) -replace '"','')| select-object -expand VersionInfo | select-object -expand CompanyName
```

Comment: `foreach ($item in get-wmiobject win32_service)  
   
{Write-Host $Item.Name,$item.StartMode,$item.State, $(get-childitem -path ($item.pathname -replace '"','' )|select-object -expand VersionInfo | select-object -expand CompanyName -ErrorAction Continue ) 
}`


This works for some and doesn't for some :(..... @MikeShepard